# Adding time to Nov. 2nd gives error

Tags: php, date

I'm having some problems adding a date.

```
$test = strtotime('nov 02 2014');
$test_date = date('D, M. jS, Y' ,(1.0*86400) + $test); 
echo $test_date;
```

returns `Sun, Nov. 2nd, 2014`

changing input to `nov 01` and `nov 03` return the expected strings.

Comment: The code works fine for me! See: http://ideone.com/PCDcPH

Comment: strtotime() is not meant to be used for date math. DateTime() is better suited for it as it handles leap years and DST.

Comment: OR maybe try it with "+ 1 day" Like this: `$test = "nov 02 2014";
 echo $test_date = date('D, M. jS, Y' ,strtotime($test . ' + 1 day')); `

Comment: I went with above +1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$test = "nov 02 2014";
echo $test_date = date('D, M. jS, Y' ,strtotime($test . ' + 1 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Daylight Saving Time ended on November 2, 2014. This means that November 2, 2014 lasted longer than the 86,400 seconds you're adding to the date!

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. Thanks. Went with +1 day